# SQL/DB2 - How can I choose which rows to use aggregate functions on, and which to ignore?

Tags: sql, db2, sum, aggregate

I'm sure this is a simple problem for SQL/DB2 gurus, but I'm still a novice and I can't think my way through this.

I have a table with four columns: Amount, ID1, ID2, and Date. Here's a sample of the data:

```
Amount  ID1 ID2 Date
3,220   127 149 Dec 1
3,220   127 424 Dec 1
637     130 149 Dec 1
637     130 424 Dec 1
2232    161 149 Dec 1
2232    161 424 Dec 1
1221    372 149 Dec 1
1221    372 424 Dec 1
1221    372 149 Jun 1
1221    372 424 Jun 1
554     54  149 Dec 1
554     54  424 Dec 1
554     54  149 Jun 1
554     54  424 Jun 1
```

So, what I'm trying to do is get a SUM() of the Amounts, for each ID1, ignoring ID2, and only for the currentmost Date. It's the date that's causing me the trouble. The closest I can get it is this:

```
Sum Amounts
6440
1274
4464
4884
1108
```

When what I want is this:

```
Sum Amounts
6440
1274
4464
2442
2216
```

What I really want is for the last two numbers to only SUM() the amounts for Jun 1, and ignore Dec 1. To basically take the currentmost dates.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT id1, SUM(amount)
FROM table1 a
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date)
              FROM table1 b
              WHERE a.id1 = b.id1
                AND a.id2 = b.id2)
GROUP BY id1
```

Comment: +1 - Although this will of course only work correctly on date columns that are actual date types, or numeric/character types sorted as `YYYYMMDD` or similar (this is mostly in reference to the fact that DB2 is often deployed on iSeries systems, which may contain legacy databases where... just about anything goes, sometimes).

Comment: Thank you very much for your succinct reply. Correlated subqueries still hurt my brain, but I was able to rejigger my query into the format you provided, and I got the data I needed. You rock!

Comment: @Adam, if the answer works for you, you can "accept" it as correct by clicking the checkmark under the voting buttons over on the left side.  :-)